# How can I make all fields in Django admin not required by default?

Tags: django, admin, models

I may want these fields to be required at another point on a form, but for now how can I set all fields from my model to not required for the admin? Id prefer not required to be default if that is possible. To elaborate...I go to enter data into the django admin form, but it does not save it because it says that the other fields are required. Is there a way for me to fix this for just the admin? Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: If your `Model` has such fields as `blank=False` or `null=False` (depending on the field), two things will happen:

1. Yoy MUST create a custom `ModelForm` having each same field declared, each with `required=False`
2. Such model will *make boom* when trying to save it to database (because null values cannot be passed to `null=False` columns).

So, in first place, you must have all your fields in your model as `null=True` and `blank=True`. Consequently, and by-default, `ModelForm` classes will be created with fields with the same restrictions - in this case, having `required=False`. So it will be *open* by default, and you can safely use a `ModelAdmin` as always. **BUT** this implies you must declare an explicit `ModelForm` class for customers/guests, with explicit same-fields but having `required=True` (edited. by default the fields would be created with required=False, since the database had blank=False in the example I gave).

ModelAdmin does not have a way to freely-open form fields by itself - not even Forms have ways to say "Do you remember this field declared in the parent? well: I want to have it but without the `required` in True".

Comment: Thank you for your answer...To me, having to write required = False over and over again violates the DRY principle. Is that true? Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: It does not break the DRY since you are actually changing the behavior you expect. I miswrote the anwer. Let me fix it.

Comment: Answer updated: for client forms (i.e. forms not intended to belong to admin) you have to explicitly create each field using `required=True`

Comment: So we wanted to be able to save long forms partially, setting all fields to required=False then overriding clean() seemed to be the best way. Without including a 'partial' key in the POST, our clean iterates over the fields raises an exception anytime they're blank.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that seems to be possible is to write your own models fields that would have required=False and blank=True by default. Otherwise you would be breaking database.